# ublox RXM messages

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are using the ublox_gps package to log data from my C94-M8P evaluation board. Specifically, we are interested in using the raw GNSS data for positioning algorithms. For this purpose, we need to use ublox RXM messages. I configured our node to publish all supported messages (see config file below).

When I start our ublox_gps node, there are some messages published:

```
user@pc:~$ rostopic list                                                                                                                    /diagnostics                                                                                                                                                 /rosout                                                                                                                                                      /rosout_agg                                                                                                                                                  /ublox/aidalm                                                                                                                                                /ublox/aideph                                                                                                                                                /ublox/fix                                                                                                                                                   /ublox/fix_velocity                                                                                                                                          /ublox/monhw                                                                                                                                                 /ublox/navclock                                                                                                                                              /ublox/navposecef                                                                                                                                            /ublox/navpvt                                                                                                                                                /ublox/navsat                                                                                                                                                /ublox/navstatus                                                                                                                                             /ublox/navsvin
```

However, there are no RXM messages (such as rxmraw), although these message formats are supported by ublox_gps. If I check the configuration of my receiver via u-center, RXM messages are sent frequently.

When I try the same with an older u-blox receiver (EVK-6H), RXM messages are generated (rxmalm, rxmeph, rxpraw, rxmsfrb).

So did I miss a point in my configuration? Or is there any other reason why no RXM messages are generated on newer u-blox devices?

This is my config file:

```
# Config                                                                                                                                                     debug: 1                    # Range 0-4 (0 means no debug statements will print)                                                                             device: /dev/ttyS11                                                                                                                                          frame_id: gps                                                                                                                                                raw_data: true                 # Device supports raw data output                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          rate: 1                     # Measurement rate in Hz                                                                                                         nav_rate: 1                 # in number of measurement cycles                                                                                                                            # in number of navigation solutions                                                                                              enable_ppp: false                                                                                                                                            dr_limit: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               dat:                                                                                                                                                           set: false                # Do not set the user configured datum                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        # GNSS Config, verify which GNSS are supported by your device                                                                                                gnss:                                                                                                                                                          gps: true                 # (not required since it defaults to true)                                                                                         glonass: true                                                                                                                                                beidou: false                                                                                                                                                qzss: false                                                                                                                                                  sbas: false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             # Time mode                                                                                                                                                  tmode3 : 0    # 0 - disabled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              inf:                                                                                                                                                           all: true                   # Whether to display INF messages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           # Message subscriptions                                                                                                                                      subscribe:                                                                                                                                                     all: true                 # Subscribe to all messages                                                                                                        aid:                                                                                                                                                           all: false                # ... except AID messages                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   publish:                                                                                                                                                       all: true                                                                                                                                                    nav:                                                                                                                                                           all:true                                                                                                                                                   rxm:                                                                                                                                                           all:true
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289214/ublox-rxm-messages/) by [alblinks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34745/alblinks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After further inspection and testing it turned out to be an issue caused by some inaccurate formulation in u-blox protocoll specification. Details can be found on the [Github page](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/ublox/issues/30).

---

Originally posted by [alblinks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34745/alblinks/) with karma: 16 on 2018-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0